# Google Compute Engine network ingress throughput speed

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to figure out what can be expected as the average **ingress** throughput speed to my Compute Engine instance on the Google cloud platform. There is quite a lot of information out there regarding the **egress** throughput speed, including [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#egress_throughput_caps) detailed computation.
However, besides stating that ingress is free of charge, I was not able to find any info on how to compute or estimate ingress throughput. So I tried to benchmark this figure like so:
Using a 4Mbps **upload** internet connection (as measured on speedtest.net), I initiated a large file upload to my instance. The code on the instance just saves the incoming file to the instance's persistent disk (a standard rotating disk type).
Looking at the network traffic chart for that instance on the Developer's Console during the upload, I'm only seeing 147KB/s which translates to about 1.1Mbps (which is quite disappointing in my view). Is this the max expected ingress traffic throughput ? 
Looking at the disk traffic chart, during the upload I'm seeing a disk write figure of 392KB/s. How can I be writing 392KB/s when I'm only getting 147KB/s through the network? (Is this related to the data redundancy mechanism for persistent disks?)
Thanks for shedding some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

As your internet connection speed is limited to 4Mbps, testing GCE instance ingress using your connection is not a good idea and the results will be limited to the slower connection which is yours. I suggest testing ingress against major network providers or other VM instance from different regions.

As an example, I downloaded 1GB file from http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip to my GCE instance and I got 20MBps (160mbps) speed.

http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html

However this is a public link and other people could be downloading at the same time, so I'm not sure if the speed is limited by which side.
Keep in mind that for testing ingress speed, the egress throughput speed of the other node should be faster or at least equal to ingress of the testing target.

Comment: I understand that I'm supposed to be limited to max 4Mbps when using a 4Mbps upload connection, However, I'm only getting about 1.1 Mbps, far lower. Anyway, I'll give your suggestion a try.